# How to change a string-formatted element in an array?

Tags: replacement, list-manipulation

I have an array called Array7 in which a typical element, let's say `Array7[5][[22]]`, looks like this:

`{"2021-03-01 00:46", 1.20822, 1.20828, 1.20822, 1.20826}` .

So element `Array7[5][[22]][[1]]` is the string `2021-03-01 00:46`. This checks out as a string by giving `True` in response to `StringQ`. The enclosing `Array7[5][[22]]`, meanwhile, answers `True` to `ArrayQ`.

Now I want to change the month and day in `Array7[5][[22]][[1]]` to "10-03". I can get the required new element like this:

`StringReplacePart[Array7[5][[22]][[1]], {"10-03"}, {6, 10}]]` ,

which yields `2021-10-03 00:46` as it should.

But when I try to "save" this as the "new" `Array7[5][[22]][[1]]` by using

`Array7[5][[22]][[1]] = StringReplacePart[Array7[5][[22]][[1]], {"10-03"}, {6, 10}]`

I get the error message

`Set::setps: Array7[5] in the part assignment is not a symbol.`

Comment: What is `Array7[5]` ? Why the [5] and not [[5]] ? Is it a list or an Association, or something else? It certainly should not be turning `Array7` into `Array[7]`. Also `Array` is a built in function so you should use lowercase to avoid confusion - although that doesn't explain the issue here.

Comment: `Array7[5]` is an array. `Array7[5][[22]]` is also an array. `Array7[5][[22]][[1]]` is a string. I made an error in the last line of the question. The error message is `Array7[5] in the part assignment is not a symbol.`

Comment: Yes I know that, but what I'm asking is how Array7 is defined - for all we know Array7[5] could be a function Array7 called with argument 5, in which case it's not a variable you can assign to. Please clarify what Array7 actually is.

Comment: I do not fully understand your question. Please can you tell me how I can find out what it actually is, and I will tell you. It is a bunch of data I imported from a .csv file.

Comment: You cannot assign to something like x[1][[22]] = ..., you can only assign to symbols like x1[[22]] = ... . I suggest you change how you're importing the data so that you do `mydata = Import["mycsvfile.csv","CSV"]` which will put all the data in a nested list mydata, instead of putting it in this cryptic `Array7[5]` variable

Comment: @ruffle Try evaluating `Head[Array7]`; what do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Using a smaller input data with the same structure as the one in OP:

```
SeedRandom[1];

dates = DateString[#, 
   {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day", " " , "Hour", ":", "Minute"}] & /@ 
  DateRange[DateObject[{2021, 1, 1, RandomReal[{0, 12}], RandomReal[{0, 59}]}], 
     DateObject[{2021, 1, 31, 0, 0}], {1, "Day"}];
 
array7[n_] := Array[Flatten[{RandomChoice[dates], RandomInteger[n, 4]}] &, 10];

array7[5] // Column
```

[image]

```
array7[5][[9]]
```

[image]

```
srp = StringReplacePart[ {"10-03"}, {6, 10}];
```

We can use [`ReplacePart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html) to modify `array7[5][[9]][[1]]` using the function `srp`:

```
ReplacePart[array7[5], {9, 1} -> srp[array7[5][[9, 1]]]];

array7[5] // Column
```

[image]

```
array7[5][[9]]
```

[image]